# How to show and hide the data when the particular condition is true in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page In that created the map and right side placed the data to display something about the map (i.e created the circle in the map of 5km radius if the marker inside the circle show the details of the marker).

I have written the if condition for the marker comes inside the circle it should be turned to red otherwise blue.

And in Html I have created the bootstrap tabs with id (drones).

**component.ts**

```
inQuadrant(quadrant) {
    var inPolygon = this.isMarkerInsidePolygon(this.droneMarker, quadrant);
    if (inPolygon) {
      quadrant.setStyle({color: 'red'});
       const isRed=true;
    } else {
      quadrant.setStyle({color: '#3388ff'});
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade " id="Drones" >
    <ul class="list-group card"  id="dd">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of datas">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <div class="card-body">
    <img src="{{drone01.iconref}}" width="90" height="90">
    
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**So my requirement is how to show and hide the data when the drone comes in side(the data of id=drones should have to be shown) and outside (the data of id=drones have to be disappear)**

Can anyone help me regarding this.I have tried multiple ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're approaching this in a very non-angular way - it's a bit difficult to give a good answer with the limited amount of code you're providing, but here goes:

If you wish to hide things, you can either:

Use `*ngIf` to display or not display the item, or bind to the CSS `visibility`-property, eg.: `[visibility]=isHidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible'`.

But I might be misunderstanding your question?

Manipulating HTMLElements (`quadrant.setStyle`) is an anti-pattern in angular, you should instead use property bindings.

Comment: I think I need to add that there are several other ways of adjusting visiibility (adjusting the `display`-property is one of them) - too many to mention here.